# HighCharts: drawing graph paper for ECG on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, graph, highcharts

in my Android app I found the need to draw, in a part of my activity, the result of an ECG bluetooth device acquisition; in other activity i can draw graph to visualize other vital parameters using HighCharts without problems, but for ECG a lot of challanges spawned!

The first, and most difficult at the time, is to draw the graph paper where the ECG lies; for those who doesn't know, it's a special grid composed by squares (ticks), major ones composed by 5 minor ones, representing time on X axis (0.2s major tick, 0.04s minor ticks) and voltage on Y axis (0.5mV major ticks, 0.1mV minor ticks).

My goal is to draw this graph paper keeping the size of these squares fixed, for example, 25dp for the major ticks (thus 5d for the minor ticks),both on vertical and horizontal.

Using various HighCharts properties, as

- setTickPixelInterval
- setTickInterval
- setMinotTickInterval

and more, when the duration of the acquisition changes, the graph stretches to reduce the graph length (also using the scrollableArea) modifying the desidered tick dimension.

There's a way to fix the tick dimension in a way that HighChart won't ever modify it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use [xAxis.tickPositions](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions) options to set an array with specific ticks on the x-axis. [xAxis.tickPositioner](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner) This option runs a Callback Function that returns an array indicating where the ticks are located on the axis.

Comment: Thanks! I solved the problem, but another one comes! I have to put my chart in a specific part of my layout. At the beginning I tried to retrieve width and height of this layout and I obtained, for example, 800x600, so I put these values into chart.setWidth(800) and chart.setHeight(600) but the chart doesn't fit in the layout, seems that dimensions changes at runtime. How can I measure real time dimension of my layout or fit the chart to my effective layout dimension? 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The height and width of the `HIChart` object are in pixels and what you got from your container is probably the value in dp. You need to convert these values to pixels and use that value for the height/width of the chart.

This will really only change the size of the chart that is in the container, i.e. in our `HIChartView`. I would rather not move the height/width values of the chart but operate directly on the `HIChartView`.

Comment: "The height and width of the HIChart object are in pixels and what you got from your container is probably the value in dp" I thinks it's wrong, the View.getWidth/getHeight of the container returns the pixels, but maybe those pixels are not the real one. Anyway I need it to set a minumun height and width to avoid pixel strecth, and the only way I can set these values are on the HiChart object, on HiChartView there aren't methods to do it.

Comment: Height and width fields of the HIChart object, they are in pixels. I suspect that the `HIChartView` is additionally wrapped in some container so if you know its dimensions then use them to set it to HIChart. You could try setting wrap content on one of the HIChartView dimensions (the other dimension must have a match parent or fixed value in dp) and not worry. If you want better help we need to see your code.